# What is the reason for flock() to return FALSE?

Tags: php

PHP manual says that calling flock returns TRUE if lock was successful and FALSE if not. If file is blocked by other process, then flock should wait until it's unblocked (since we don't use LOCK_NB). There is nothing about the timeout in docs, which can interrupt waiting, so obviously flock will wait infinitely until gets lock.

But sometime I getting FALSE from flock() in my multithreaded scripts. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Maybe because of "all accessing programs have to use the same way of locking or it will not work"?

Comment: False would be the result if there's a reason for not getting the lock other than "it's already acquired" such as e.g. "the operating system wouldn't let me check if the file is locked or not".

Comment: If you want to get anything but blind (and unlikely to answer you) guesses, you'd have to give more details like your OS, the type of resource you're trying to `flock()` on and further clarify what you mean by "sometime".

Comment: Multithreaded PHP? While its possible it is *very* unusual, in which case its odd that you should mention it in such an offhand manner. Particularly when it often goes hand in hand with asynchronous I/O (which has further complications with locking). Can you clarify what extension you are using for the multi-threading?

Comment: I use pcntl_fork() under FreeBSD. I wanted to know in general, how it is possible to get FALSE if flock should wait until lock is free.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problem recently and made a small research. If you look at the [source code of the PHP flock function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/standard/flock_compat.c), you can see the implementation depends on OS the code is compiled on.

For *nix systems there is:

```
ret = fcntl(fd, operation & LOCK_NB ? F_SETLK : F_SETLKW, &flck);
```

It means OS level fcntl function is used.

[Manual for fcntl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) says:

> F_SETLKW (struct flock *)
>
> As for F_SETLK, but if a conflicting lock is held on the file, then wait for that lock to be released.  **If a signal is caught while  waiting,  then  the call is interrupted** and (after the signal handler has returned) returns immediately (with return value -1 and errno set to EINTR; see signal(7)).

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this can be a "security" restriction in php.ini.

So also check with `phpinfo()` whether `flock` is listed in the `disabled_functions` list:

[image: Example of phpinfo() with disabled flock function]